# Get location updates using location client and location request with GPS only

Tags: android, gps

In my app i get location updates using location client and location request. And i implement GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener. And my app work like a champ.
My question is: When GPS fix a location The onLocationChanged(Location location) called. What's happen when GPS lost signal?. How i can handle this case with Location client??

Answer (score 0):

The new Location Api gets the best location using the sensors(gps, wifi, etc) on your phone and you do not need to worry from which provider it is getting the location. So, you do not need to handle that. On the callback or in the pending intent, it will return the best location when you'll need according to the setInterval() & setFastestInterval() that you have specified. 
This video link might help in the clear understanding of how simple the api is.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bte_GHuxUGc&spfreload=10%20Message%3A%20Unexpected%20end%20of%20input%20(url%3A%20http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DBte_GHuxUGc)